# AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_aggregate'

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Django app and I have a view that display both sides of an `object_set` (a reverse many to many). Because of this, I want to query all of the objects on both sides at the same time. Specifically speaking, I want to have all of the `Signup` objects that are associated with each `Event`.

(The view page format should look like this.)

```
Event (0)
-- Signup (0.0)
-- Signup (0.1)
-- Signup (0.2)
-- Signup (0.3)
Event (1)
-- Signup (1.0)
-- Signup (1.1)
Event (3)
-- Signup (3.0)
-- Signup (3.1)
-- Signup (3.2)
-- Signup (3.3)
...
```

The code is as follows:

```
class TournamentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Tournament

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        tournament_id = self.get_object().pk
        events = Event.objects.annotate(
            cached_signups=(
                Signup.objects
                    .filter(event_id=OuterRef('pk'), tournament_id=tournament_id, dropped=False)
                    .order_by('created')
                    .defer('tournament')
            )
        ).all()
        context['events'] = events
        return context
```

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback:    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\detail.py" in get
  106.         context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\PycharmProjects\gwspo-signups-website\gwhs_speech_and_debate\tournament_signups\views.py" in get_context_data
  171.                     .defer('tournament')    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)    

File "C:\Users\werdn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in annotate
  1000.             if alias in annotations and annotation.contains_aggregate:    

Exception Type: AttributeError at /tournaments/detail/lobo-howl/
Exception Value: 'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_aggregate'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening and it seems to be happening on the `Signups.objects` query but even with `Signups.objects.all()`, this Exception seems to be triggered. That leads me to believe that this is not an issue with the use of `OuterRef('pk')`.

Comment: That's not possible afaik without using raw SQL. You could wrap your `Signup` query in a `Subquery()` (see [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)) but that only works for specific values, not for the entire objects. If you just want to optimise your database fetches, you should use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See @dirkgroten's as to why the question produces the error. Read on for an alternate method that solves the issue.

The reason why @dirkgroten's answer wouldn't work is that the model definition for `Event` doesn't include a value `signups`. However, since the ManyToMany relationship is defined on the `Signup` model, I *can* get the `prefetch_related` to work off of the `Signup` query, as we see below.

```
signups = Signup.objects.filter(
    tournament_id=tournament_id
).prefetch_related(
    'event',
    ...
)
context['signups'] = signups
context['events'] = signups.values('event', 'event__name', ...).distinct().order_by('event__name')
```

(Note that `order_by` is required in order for `distinct`  to work and that `values()` returns a dict, not a queryset.)

Comment: I've added some information to show how to do the prefetch for a reverse relationship.

Comment: @dirkgroten I see that -- the reverse with `signup_set` doesn't throw any errors but also I think that it doesn't prefetch. The `.query` value is: `SELECT "tournament_signups_event"."id" FROM "tournament_signups_event" ORDER BY "tournament_signups_event"."created" DESC` (when just selecting the id)

Comment: You mean when adding `.values('id')` to it? Django is smart enough to only query what’s needed when the query is actually executed. Also `prefetch_related` actually does two queries (Django can’t do it in one), the second one is executed when you’re actually accessing any of the related objects.

Comment: Ah. Good call. So when querying `Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('signup_set')`, then iterating over the result in the view, each event's `signup_set` prints as `tournament_signups.Signup.None`. Also, if I try to iterate (like: `{% for signup in event.signup_set %}<p>{{signup}}</p>{% endfor %}`), I get a `'RelatedManager' object is not iterable` error. It doesn't seem like this method is actually returning any values in the `signup_set`.

Comment: It is. You need to loop through `event.signup_set.all`

Comment: Of course. My bad. Despite that, this drastically increases the time to load (~400 ms with my answer to ~3000 with yours). Considering that, I'm going to mark the other answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just put a `Query` inside an `annotation`, since an `annotation` is like adding a column to the row you're fetching. Django supports the concept of a `Subquery` in an annotation, but that only works if you're fetching one aggregated value of the related model. This would work for example:

```
signups = Signup.objects
                .filter(event_id=OuterRef('pk'), tournament_id=tournament_id, dropped=False)
                .order_by('created')
                .defer('tournament')
events = Event.objects.annotate(latest_signup=Subquery(signups.values('date')[:-1]))
```

If you just want to optimise database access so that you don't make a database query for each `Event` to fetch the related `Signup`s, you should use `prefetch_related`:

```
events = Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('signups')
```

Since you didn't show how your models are defined, I'm assuming this is a reverse M2M relationship:

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    events = models.ManyToManyField(to='Event', related_name='signups')
```

If you don't specify a `related_name`, the attribute to use for the prefetch is `signup_set` (which is not documented anywhere and very confusing since for aggregations it's the lowercase name of the model):

```
events = Event.objects.all().prefetch_related('signup_set')
```

This will make two queries: One for the `Event` objects, and only one extra for all the related `Signup` objects (instead of `Event.objects.count()` queries). The [documentation for `prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) contains some useful information on how this works.

Comment: `prefetch_related` seems to fail: `Cannot find 'signup' on Event object, 'signup' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()` (this also happens for 'signups'). I think that's since the M2M exists on the `Signup` model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query all `Event`/`Signup` pairs in your ManyToMany relationship, the most straightforward approach would be to query the helper table that stores just those pairs (as two `ForeignKey`s).

To get easy access to that table, you can make it a Django model by using the `through` option of `ManyToManyField`, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

Such a `through` model always exists implicitly for any Django model by using the `through` option of `ManyToManyField m2nfield` and can be accessed via `Model.m2nfield.through.objects`.

Or you don't use a `ManyToManyField` at all and just create a separate model with two `ForeignKeyField`s to represent the pairs.